# I'm getting undefined when trying to iterate through my json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to get a JSON response and iterate through the data.  Here is the response I get:

```
[{"category":{"category":"sell"},"subcategory":{"subcategory":"cars"}}]
```

Then I run that through JSON.parse() and then when I try to access data I get undefined.

```
for (var category in myJson) {
     console.log(category.category); //this is undefined
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this isn't working as I am intending to? Is my JSON format incorrect?

Comment: what browser are you using? Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Side note. That is a strange format. Why not `[{"category":"sell", "subcategory":"cars"}]`?

Comment: @jessegavin it's the format of the query response with the framework i'm using.  There are many categories and subcategories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i in myJson)
   console.log(myJson[i]);
```

Your code is wrong because you're trying to access the 'category' property of the iterator variable.

Comment: This was the solution.  I guess it was a stupid mistake on my part.  Thanks for the help :)  I'll mark as accepted in a couple minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing `category.category` where you need `myJson[category]`.